# useState not working - wanting to keep track of two variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to keep track of a question and an answer inputted by users, over the lifecycle of a component / feature.

Essentially - There is a random number array produced, which the user then remembers and entered, and the data of what the question was and the input is kept, for 6 inputs.

The code is as below.

```js
function Baseline(props) {
  const [Stage, setStage] = React.useState(0) // walkthrough Status
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(false) //timer off, on, or in input stage.
  const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState()
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([])
  const [answer, setAnswer] = React.useState()
  const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState([])
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = React.useState(false)

  // RandomString generates a random string of length n
  // var numbers = MakeId(0 + 2 * Stage);
  var numbers = 'qSLeD9D0PlSE' + Stage
  //qSLeD9D0PlSE

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      if (answers.length === 6) {
        //here you would fire your submit to server
        setIsSubmit(true)
      }
      //this sets the time to wait, being 3 seconds
      if (time) {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          // console.log(answers);
          console.log(questions)
          // do anything, this block runs after the timeout has "expired"
          // could even set state
          setTime('input')
          console.log('The timeout was called.')
        }, 3000) // timeout expires in 6000 ms
        // make sure to clear the timeout on component unmount to avoid memory loss issues

        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
        // this callback function runs only on component unmount, not re-renders
      }
    },
    [time],
    [answers]
  )

  function handleOnChange(e) {
    setAnswer(e.target.value)
  }

  function handleClick(e, numbers) {
    if (!isSubmit) {
      setAnswers([...answers, answer])
      setTime(true)
    } else {
      setTime(false)
    }
    // setTheArray([, newElement]);
    setQuestions([...questions, numbers])
    setStage(Stage + 1)
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('The link was clicked.')
  }
  let testInput

  if (time == true) {
    testInput = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Stage {Stage}</div>

        <div className='underline font-light    items-center justify-center'>
          Hold the numbers in your head!
        </div>
        <div className='uppercase bg-white tracking-widest  text-center font-bold text-5xl shadow p-4 items-center'>
          {numbers}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  } else if (time == 'input') {
    testInput = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Stage {Stage}</div>

        <div className='font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg'>Enter Numbers</div>
        <div className='bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 items-center justify-center'>
          <div className=' items-center '>
            <label for='answer' className='sr-only font-thin px-2 pb-4 text-lg'>
              Answer
            </label>
            <input
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              type='text'
              value={answer}
              name='answer'
              id='answer'
              className=' items-center shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md'
              placeholder='Enter Here'
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  } else if (isSubmit == true && time == false) {
    testInput = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p className='text-lg leading-7 text-gray-500 mb-5'>
          You have completed the test! here are your answers
        </p>
        <ul>
          {answers.map((item) => (
            <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  } else if (time == false) {
    testInput = (
      <p className='text-lg leading-7 text-gray-500 mb-5'>
        You are about to do a small short term memory test. A few letters will flash on your
        computer monitor for 3 seconds. Your job is to write down as many letters as you can
        remember
      </p>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Sidebar_Users dashboard={"Progress Map"}>
      <div className='py-8 min-h-full container mx-auto   '>
        <div className='mt-2 mb-8 text-3xl leading-8 font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10'>
          Working Memory Test
        </div>
        {testInput}
        <ButtonBaseline
          time={time}
          Stage={Stage}
          handleClick={handleClick}
          isSubmit={isSubmit}
          numbers={numbers}
          // onSubmit={onSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    </Sidebar_Users>
  )
}

const Sidebar_Users = ({ children }) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
)

const ButtonBaseline = ({handleClick}) => (
  <button
    onClick={(e, numbers) => handleClick(e)}
    className='bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700shadow-xl font-semibold rounded-full fixed right-8 bottom-20 text-xl px-8 py-3 sm:right-16 sm:bottom-16 text-white sm:text-xl sm:py-3 sm:px-7  flex items-center focus:outline-none'
  >
    <svg
      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      width='24'
      height='24'
      viewBox='0 0 24 24'
      fill='none'
      stroke='currentColor'
      strokeWidth='2'
      strokeLinecap='round'
      strokeLinejoin='round'
      className='-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5'
    >
      <circle cx='12' cy='12' r='10'></circle>
      <polygon points='16.24 7.76 14.12 14.12 7.76 16.24 9.88 9.88 16.24 7.76'></polygon>
    </svg>
    <span>Next Step </span>
  </button>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Baseline />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Now I am having trouble keeping the Question (being the numbers variable) tracked against the input variable. It just won't stay in the setState given. I'm not really sure why.

Additionally, I'd prefer to keep a key:value pair in one setState statement, but on using setState({}) instead of [], i.e., array versus dictionary, it won't work.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Your code example is too complex, please provide a minimal working example of the issue you are having.

Comment: Just a remark. I did not follow the code entirely. I only noticed `useEffect` is provided with 3 params instead of 2. It might be that `[answers]` is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is highly complex and difficult to follow. This makes it difficult to see what the issue is, and where the issue is coming from.

With that said it looks like **you are not passing in your `numbers` variable into your `handleClick` onClick handler.**

In your button component you are currently doing `onClick={(e,numbers) => handleClick(e)}`.

This means in your onClick handler where you have `handleClick(e, numbers)` `numbers` in this block might be undefined.

Generally speaking you should avoid re-using a variable name in child scopes because it can be confusing and cause issues.

On top of this, it looks like you need to reformat the useEffect dependancy array.

You should only have one array, so instead of `[time], [answers]` you should have `[time, answers]`

---

**Simplest fix:**

**Change `onClick={(e, numbers) => handleClick(e)}` to `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, numbers)}`.**

---

**Better fix:**

Change **`function handleClick(e, numbers)`** to **`function handleClick(e)`**

Change **`<ButtonBaseline ... handleClick={handleClick} numbers={numbers} />`** to **`<ButtonBaseline ... handleClick={handleClick} />`**

Finally change **`<button ... onClick={(e,numbers) => handleClick(e)} />`** to **`<button onClick={handleClick} ... />`**

---

**Best fix:**

The above fixes will hopefully solve your issue, but the code you have posted is complex, may cause more issues, will be hard to maintain and to debug.

Because of this I would highly recommend **refactoring this component** to be as simplistic as possible.

If you are still having this issue after you have refactored your code, you will be able to repost it and the community will be much better equipped to be able to debug this and help you.